# Xamarin Android can't set new event's date

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-calendar

I can create a new Event in calendar, but I can't set the datetime of the event.
I can set the Location, title, description and so on.

When debugging, I can see the variables dtStart and dtEnd corretly (for testing, I'm using the string "15/05/2016 15:00:00" in the format dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss - brasilian pattern)

Thank you for your help!

```
btnAdicionarAgenda.Click += delegate
        {
            Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionInsert);
            calIntent.SetData(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri);
            calIntent.SetType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, calendarTitle);
            calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, calendarDescription);

            DateTime dtStart = DateTime.ParseExact(retNotificacao.get("dt_evento"), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            DateTime dtEnd = dtStart.AddHours(1);

            long lDtStart = Utils.GetDateTimeMS(dtStart.Year, dtStart.Month, dtStart.Day, dtStart.Hour, dtStart.Minute);
            long lDtEnd = Utils.GetDateTimeMS(dtEnd.Year, dtEnd.Month, dtEnd.Day, dtEnd.Hour, dtEnd.Minute);

            calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, lDtStart);
            calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, lDtEnd);

            calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "UTC");
            calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, "UTC");
            calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventLocation, Session.nmEscolaAluno);



            StartActivity(calIntent);
        };
```

Utils.cs:

```
public static long GetDateTimeMS(int yr, int month, int day, int hr, int min)
    {
        Calendar c = Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.TimeZone.Default);

        c.Set(Calendar.DayOfMonth, day);
        c.Set(Calendar.HourOfDay, hr);
        c.Set(Calendar.Minute, min);
        c.Set(Calendar.Month, month);
        c.Set(Calendar.Year, yr);

        return c.TimeInMillis;
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: No, the Android Calendar opens, it shows the event, ith the title, description, location, but it ignores the date passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do NOT use `Dtstart` and `Dtend`, the documentation and examples that are posted (Google's and Xamarin's) are just **wrong**.

The string consts should be "EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME" and "EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME".

#### Change:

```
calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, lDtStart);    
calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, lDtEnd);
```

#### To:

```
calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.ExtraEventBeginTime, lDtStart);
calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.ExtraEventEndTime, lDtEnd);
```

#### Results of "15/05/2016 15:00:00" (plus one hour):

- Start msec: 1466028054652
- End msec: 1466031654659

---

#### Screen cap of event created:

[image]

Comment: Ohh man! Thank you thiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiis much! You saved my weekend, after 3 days of headache.

Comment: I just Addes a month-- in the GetDateTimeMS method, 'cause Java month starts with 0.

Comment: @WilliamBorgo no problem, you can blame Google (I guess).. their docs are really screwed up on this matter... it is strange that Xamarin has posted example code with the same problem, I'm assuming it was not really tested